# How do you turn off assertions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, assert

After debugging my MATLAB code, I'd like to be able to turn off assertions to get a bit of extra speed if possible. (The expression inside the assertion is very short and quick, but there are a lot of calls inside tight loops, so it adds up. Yes, I profiled.) How do I do that globally in MATLAB? I'm looking for something akin to defining `NDEBUG` in C/C++, or enabling optimization in Python, or `-disableassertions` flag in Java. Find/replace of `assert(` with `%assert(` is too ugly for my taste.

Comment: The way to avoid computing the expression by logical short-circuiting is more invasive than overriding `assert`, but I think it gets the job done.  Updated answer with details and example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It occurred to me after posting these solutions that while effectively disabling assertions, they don't prevent execution of the expression.  Perhaps you could exploit short-circuiting of logical expressions (`true || expr`) to avoid evaluating `expr`.  This could be done by using a `global NDEBUG` in place of that `true`.  That is, use `assert(NDEBUG || expr)` so that `expr` won't be evaluated when `NDEBUG` is `true`.  For example,

```
% parentCode.m (or typed on command prompt)
global NDEBUG; NDEBUG=true;
testassertions % test script below

% testassertions.m
global NDEBUG
if isempty(NDEBUG), NDEBUG=false; end
assert(NDEBUG || fprintf('NO\n')==2) % did fprintf write 3 characters? (no, 4)
disp('Assertions are off!')
```

To use this approach, you would oviously need to modify your `assert` calls to use the `(NDEBUG || expr)` approach, and you would add the two lines to bring in the `global`, as done in `testassertions.m` above.  This is not the "switch" you are looking for, but it would avoid computing `expr`, which seems to be the real goal here.

### Override with custom `assert.m`

You can override `assert` with your own `assert.m` *at the top* of your path.  Just use `varargin` and it will work:

```
function assert(varargin)
end
```

The first time you run it or `rehash` your path, you get a warning, then it's fine!

```
>> assert(false)
>> assert(false,'No error here',[])
>>
```

No errors, no warnings.

### Override with anonymous `assert`

Possibly easier to manage is an anonymous `assert` function with variable inputs and no outputs:

```
assert = @(varargin) deal;
```

Here we are using `deal` with no inputs (`nargin=0`) because it just does `varargout = varargin;`.

Comment: So MATLAB has no built-in way to turn off assertions? Bummer. One problem I can see with `assert(NDEBUG || expr, ...)`, is that I would have to include `global NDEBUG` in every source file where I want to use this paradigm. I'm starting to think that a simple shell script which comments out/uncomments lines that have an assert is actually a cleaner way to go. Btw, if I override `assert` with anonymous function, can I un-override it later?

Comment: It's not the best solution, agreed.  However, since it is `global` you only need `global NDEBUG=false` run once per session, either at the command line or in a startup script.  It doesn't need to be in every source file, so it is easier than you think.  On the topic of anonymous functions, you would just clear the variable that defines the function, but the anonymous solution is less global than a .m file or the global variable option.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, to bring in the `global` you do need `global NDEBUG` in every file after you do `global NDEBUG; NDEBUG=true`.